# how to prevent observables coupling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, observable

I have a case that two observables depending on each other, causing infinite loop.

```
this.value = ko.observable();
this.selectedOptions = ko.observableArray();

this.value.subscribe(function(value){
    this.selectedOptions(value.split(', '));
});

this.selectedOptions.subscribe(function(options){
    this.value(options.join(', '));
});
```

How to prevent infinite loop and update both observebles?

Comment: post some code. it is too hard to understand what you mean.

Comment: First of all notice, that `this` in callback functions refs to Window object, not to your ViewModel

Answer (score 1):

Just break the loop.

```
this.value = ko.observable();
this.selectedOptions = ko.observableArray();

var isInnerUpdate = false;

this.value.subscribe(function(value){
  if (!isInnerUpdate) {
    isInnerUpdate = true;
    this.selectedOptions(value.split(', '));
    isInnerUpdate = false;
  }
}, this); // I think you missed 'this' ref binding

this.selectedOptions.subscribe(function(options){
  if (!isInnerUpdate) {
    isInnerUpdate = true;
    this.value(options.join(', '));
    isInnerUpdate = false;
  }
}, this);
```